# Unable to run custom dotnet command as TeamCity build step

Tags: .net, teamcity, entity-framework-migrations

Current setup:

- Server Running Ubuntu 18
- TeamCity Professional 2019.2 (build 71499)

I'm working on setting up a build task to generate SQL migration scripts using the following command:

```
dotnet ef migrations script --output "script.sql" --context MyContext
```

However, when running the build on TeamCity the build fails with the following error:

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

Process exited with code 1
```

If I run the command via the Ubuntu shell on the TeamCity server it runs without issue but when running it via TeamCity itself I get the above error message. Do I need to tell TeamCity where `dotnet` is installed? If so where?

The build step is setup as follows:

**Runner Type**: Command Line

**Run**: Custom script

**Custom script**: `dotnet ef migrations script --output "script.sql" --context MyContext`

Comment: Even I am getting the same result? No answers yet? Terrible!

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity now supports running custom **"dotnet"** commands using their .NET runner however, their documentation isn't particularly clear. You don't need to specify any values for the **"Executables"** field as **"dotnet"** is assumed and instead all additional parameters are placed in to the **"Command line parameters"** field as shown below.

[image]